# Is it possible to add fields to a document in a CouchDB validation function?

Tags: javascript, validation, couchdb

One of the things that is lost in the move to CouchDB is the ability to have default values for a field. For example, in an SQL database you can have a field called `date` that defaults to `now()`. Is it possible to do something similar in CouchDB?

From what I can tell, the only piece of code that gets run on every create and update operation is the `validate_doc_update` method of a design document. However, when we've tested it by creating a dummy validation, we can't get it to work. Here's a simple validation function that attempts to set the field `newDoc.foo`, but it never gets saved.

```
function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtr) {
    newDoc.foo = "bar!";
}
```

We've checked and verified that the `validate_doc_update` method is getting called, so it appears that if there a way to automatically add fields to a CouchDB document, using the validation function isn't the way to go. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some view logic to apply defaults when you view the doc via a view.

You could apply an [update handler](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers) to it after it's written (and possibly after subsequent changes) but that'd require another call to invoke it each time.

I would probably solve this by creating the document you're inserting as an object before you insert it and having the defaults applied there so what you write to CouchDB is already correct.

Comment: In recent versions of CouchDB [it is not allowed to modify the doc in the view](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/oW6DzLPEoEfysNJMyaLk).

Comment: Thanks for the hint on update handlers. A well crafted update handler can look and feel exactly like the normal mechanism for creating and updating documents while still adding in additional fields, such as a creation date. Also, by putting these in update functions they don't get run again after replication.