# CouchDB call update handler within validate document

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I would like to copy a document each time it goes through the validate function ant fits a specific condition. After some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810671/is-it-possible-to-add-fields-to-a-document-in-a-couchdb-validation-function), I've discovered that an update handler would perfectly do the job to copy the document.

So my question is: is it possible to call an update function within a validate function?

Answer (score 0):

The validate_doc_update function will be called automatically after an update handler. Move your condition handling to an update handler and overwrite the doc._id to a new one (e.g. req.uuid). That will create a document copy. You have to use the update handler for every write operation of the doc type you want to make copies from.